# How do I execute an executable on every computer on my LAN

Tags: windows, deployment

I have a domain full of Windows computers (some are XP, some are Vista, most are 7). I want to run a single executable, once, on each machine without leaving my seat.

I have full administrative access to the entire network.  Is there a straight forward way of doing this or am I going to have to get up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this using psexec. You can get psexec from Microsoft at:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Now what you'll need after installing that to somewhere in your PATH (for example c:\windows\system32), is a text file that has all of the hostnames that you want the command run on. Then you can simply run:

```
psexec @linktoTEXTfilehere -u username -p password commandtorunhere.exe
```

Just remember that if the filenames have any spaces in them, to surround them in quotes. Also, if you are using a domain account use the format domain\username when specifying the user to run as.

Comment: My new favourite toy! Thankyou!

Comment: what happen if the exe need to choose something ?  or clicking next button ? I need to install kaspersky internet security 2017 on all  PCs on my network

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want [PSExec from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).

e.g.

```
C:\>psexec \\* c:\bin\test.exe
```

The `\\*` part will attempt to run the specified command/program on every machine in the domain.
Look at the options for PSExec as there are a number of useful switches you can flip.